# avconv does not support setting profile for mp4/h264/aac

Tags: avconv

Hi I am trying to convert a wmv video to mp4 using h264 baseline profile.

```
avconv -i 'Video2.WMV' \
-vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -profile baseline \
-acodec aac -strict experimental \
-r 24 -b 255k -ar 44100 -ab 59k 'Video2.mp4'
```

But it is showing following errors:

```
[aac @ 0x707e40] [Eval @ 0x7fff0c8db800] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'baseline'
[aac @ 0x707e40] Unable to parse option value "baseline"
[aac @ 0x707e40] Error setting option profile to value baseline.
```

Profile setting is causing the errors. If I run the command:

```
avconv -i 'Video2.WMV' \
-vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast \
-acodec aac -strict experimental \
-r 24 -b 255k -ar 44100 -ab 59k 'Video2.mp4'
```

Then it works fine.

What is the correct method of setting h264 profile in avconv command?
Running Ubuntu 13.04 and latest libavtools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
avconv -i 'Video2.WMV' \
-vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -profile:v baseline \
-acodec aac -strict experimental \
-r 24 -b 255k -ar 44100 -ab 59k 'Video2.mp4'
```

`-profile:v` ensures the baseline profile is applied to video only

Comment: I was grabbing input from screen with `-f x11grab` but baseline didn't work, complaining with `Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height` untill i've set the pixel format to `-pix_fmt yuv420p`, The default pixel format for code libx264 it's yuv440. Now it can be playable on my phone.